# Miniconda update to new bash session

Tags: python, bash, python-3.7, miniconda

I have miniconda installed in my mac system. Back when I was installing I had downloaded the python 3.6 mac OS 64-bit (bash installer) from https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

currently, there is python 3.7 bash session is available, I tried to install the latest bash after downloading with the below command,

bash Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh

after the license process and directory set to my old one (in the home directory) I see the error

ERROR: File or directory already exists: '/Users/xxxxxxxxxx/miniconda3'
If you want to update an existing installation, use the -u option.

What am I missing here. My primary reason to update is to update the python version. Since with "conda update conda" I only get python update of the 3.6 series. I want to update to 3.7 series of python.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to update Miniconda to change the Python version.

If you want to use a different Python version for certain projects, [create new conda environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands). Each conda environment can use a different Python version, and it is completely independent of the Python version in the base environment.

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.7
```

If you want to change the Python version of the base environment, use

```
conda install -n base python=3.7
```